# Generate an error outline on TextField after user clicks on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, material-ui

I am using material-ui `TextField` component as my text field. I want to generate a red error outline when the required fields are empty after the user clicks on submit. The questions I have seen on here only illustrate when both the submit action and TextField lives in the same component but in my case both live in different components.

In materual-ui, it states I can use the `error` attribute. I have a component named `ActionsComponent` which handles all the actions on that question page like when when the user clicks on submit so when an error gets generated a modal popups to the user saying the, "required fields are empty". After this model closes, I want the empty text fields to be highlighted in red but not sure how to do that? The text field lives in the component called `QuestionOneComponent`.

```
export default function ActionsComponent() {

    const showErrors = (errors: FieldErrors) => {
        const { id } = showModal(SimpleStatusDialog, {
          title: 'Required fields are empty!',
          content: (
            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" className={cl.boxSpacing}>
              {Object.entries(errors).map(([fieldId, errorProps]) => (
                <Box display="flex" className={cl.boxSpacing}>
                  <Typography>{`${fieldId}:`}</Typography>
                  <Typography type="negative">{errorProps?.message || errorProps?.root?.message || 'This field is required'}</Typography>
                </Box>
              ))}
            </Box>
          ),
          closeFn: () => hideModal(id),
        });
      };
  
    return (
        <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" p={2} className={cl.stickyButtons}>
          <Box display="flex" className={cl.boxSpacing}>
            <Button sdsButtonType={isValid ? 'primary' : 'destructive'} onClick={handleSubmit(submitQuestions, showErrors)}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );      
}

export default function QuestionOneComponent() {

    ....

    <Typography type="negative">Please provide any additional details here</Typography>
            <TextField
              {...register('M1', { required: true })}
              placeholder="Enter relevant additional information"
              fullWidth
              multiline
    />    
}
```

Comment: Use a state that wraps both these components and pass it in the props accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `error={errors.M1?.type === 'required'}` as a TextField attribute where `errors` come from `const { register, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext();`